# Являеися ли данный способ работы CURL с Proxy правильным?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Являеися ли данный способ работы CURL запрос (на PHP) с Proxy правильным?

```
 $url ="https://www.website.com";
  $ch = curl_init($url);     
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);       
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "Proxy:Port");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильный это рабочий, а вот будет ли он работать зависит от ряда вещей (типы прокси/сайтов/протоколов и т.д.). В моих случаях обычно не повредит добавить:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5)
```

и еще

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Я добавил небольшой тест: $loadtime = time(); $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch); echo "cURL time: " . (time() - $loadtime) . "s<br />\ "; if ($response === false) { echo "cURL Error: ", curl_error($ch); } else { echo $response; }  Получаю такую ошибку:  cURL time: 1s \ cURL Error: TCP connection reset by peer и Error: SOCKS5 read timeout

Comment: @Anton Должен быть рабочий прокси, правильный PROXYTYPE ... ну и на запрашиваемых сайтах могут быть дополнительные защиты/требования.

Comment: @Anton и у меня обычно нет в коде curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true); уже не помню почему

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true); - убрал но ничего не меняется. наш IT к кот. я обратился за настройками говорит что проблема в моем коде. но найти проблему я нем могу. Что означает правильный Proxy type? это касается кода или Proxe side? На запрашиваемых сайтах без прокси все работает. проверял с дургого сервера. Может я могу как то проверить работает ли мой прокси или настроен ли он правильно ?

Comment: @Anton https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS

Comment: Без конкретного прокси и сайта гадание на кофейной гуще что не работает и почему

Comment: Дело в том что я проверил свой запрос на тот же сайт с другого сервера без прокси. все работает.

Comment: Может есть способ проверить работу или доступ через прокси серврер правильно ли он настроен?

Comment: @Anton проверить прокси можно через браузер, или еще найти бесплатных прокси несколько и попробовать работает ли скрипт через них

Comment: Как можно проверить прокси через браузер? мой прокси выглядит так: abproxy.websitename.com:port

Comment: @Anton смотря какой браузер, но наверное почти все браузеры поддерживают подключение через прокси. Загугли как в твоем браузере это делать

Comment: мой прокси выглядит так: abproxy.websitename.com:port Если Браузер подключается что может быть помехой? Файрволл?

Comment: @Anton тема валидности/типа прокси выходит за пределы вопроса по CURL и  "по фотографии" не лечится

Comment: я задаю этот вопрос т.к. он свзяан с моим вопросом. у меня нет доступа к настройкам прокси, но через браузер он работает. по крайней мере заходит на сайт, поэтому я пытаюсь выяснить причину почему мой CURL GET запрос обрывается - TCP connection reset by peer.